# How to do correct polygon rotation? ( in C# though it applies to anything )

Tags: c#, geometry, rotation, polygon

Hi I'm using this C# code to rotate polygons in my app - they do rotate but also get skewed along the way which is not what i want to happen. All the polygons are rectangles with four corners defined as 2D Vectors,

```
    public Polygon GetRotated(float radians)
    {

        Vector origin = this.Center;
        Polygon ret = new Polygon();
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
        {
            ret.Points.Add(RotatePoint(points[i], origin, radians));
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public Vector RotatePoint(Vector point, Vector origin, float angle)
    {
        Vector ret = new Vector();
        ret.X = (float)(origin.X + ((point.X - origin.X) * Math.Cos((float)angle)) - ((point.Y - origin.Y) * Math.Sin((float)angle)));
        ret.Y = (float)(origin.Y + ((point.X - origin.X) * Math.Sin((float)angle)) - ((point.Y - origin.Y) * Math.Cos((float)angle)));
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Looks okay to me, at a quick perusal. What sort of skewing are you seeing? And is there any reason you're using `float` instead of `double`?

Comment: Dysaster had it, simply adding the y term rather than subtracting fixed it. thanks to jonskeet too for the much nicer code :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like your rotation transformation is incorrect. You should use:

```
x' = x*Cos(angle) - y*Sin(angle)
y' = x*Sin(angle) + y*Cos(angle)
```

For more information, check [various sources](http://www.google.com/search?q=rotation+transformation) on the internet. :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't have any answer to why it's skewing yet, but I *do* have a suggestion to make the code clearer:

```
public Vector RotatePoint(Vector point, Vector origin, float angle)
{
    Vector translated = point - origin;
    Vector rotated = new Vector
    {
        X = translated.X * Math.Cos(angle) - translated.Y * Math.Sin(angle),
        Y = translated.X * Math.Sin(angle) + translated.Y * Math.Cos(angle)
    };
    return rotated + origin;
}
```

(That's assuming `Vector` has appropriate +/- operators defined.)

You may still need a couple of casts to `float`, but you'll still end up with fewer brackets obfuscating things. Oh, and you definitely *don't* need to cast `angle` to `float`, given that it's already declared as `float`.

EDIT: A note about the rotation matrices involved - it depends on whether you take the angle to be clockwise or anticlockwise. I wouldn't be at all surprised to find out that the matrix is indeed what's going wrong (I did try to check it, but apparently messed up)... but "different" doesn't *necessarily* mean "wrong". Hopefully the matrix *is* what's wrong, admittedly :)

Comment: +1 for suggesting readability improvements. We need more people coding for the next programmer who will maintain the code.

Answer (score 3):

I think your rotation matrix is incorrect. There should be a `+` instead of `-` in the second equation:

```
+cos  -sin
+sin  +cos
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that origin is 0,0. From your formula I would get:
X' = (X + ((X - 0) * Cos(angle)) - ((Y - 0) * Sin(angle))); 
X' = X + (X  * Cos(angle)) - (Y * Sin(angle));

Which differs from the initial formula
x' = x * cos angle - y * cos angle

So I think Jon Skeet's answer is correct and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess - are you sure the aspect ratio of your desktop resolution is the same as of the physical screen? That is, are the pixels **square**? If not, then rotating your rectangles in an arbitrary angle can make them look skewed.

Comment: I haven't had a screen with anisotropic pixels since EGA times (640x400) - I thought those beasts went the way of the dinosaur!

Comment: @nikie - not necessarily the physical pixel. You can choose a resolution different than the native screen res. This way you can get rectangular "logical" pixels when your desktop is stretched to fill the physical screen area.